# Hide parts of mesh overlapping another mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, mesh

I have thoses two meshes:

[image: two meshes]

In my game, I put the hat on the hair at runtime:

[image: hat on hairs]

As you can see, as expected, the hair is visible outise the hat part.

How can I achieve this in Unity (what kind of mask shader should I use?):

[image]

I've tryed to make a depth mask but it hides every meshes in my scene. I just want to hide the hair, not others meshes.
And what if I have two player having the same case? Would player mask hide player 2 hair? How can I avoid that?

Comment: Separate hair models that work with your hats are arguably the simplest way to go. That way, you're doing most of the work in your 3D software and swapping out the mesh in Unity. An alternative solution would be a cut-off shader which prevents the hair mesh from rendering above the hat's rim.

Comment: If your hat never rotates, you can pass the y world position of its bottom to the shader of the hair and hide every vertex whose y world position is on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do:

1. write a C# code that gets the pivot position (bottom part of the hat) and its up vector every frame.
2. build a plane with these values. The up vector would be the normal vector of the plane and a plane can be defined by a point and a normal vector.
3. I would pass the equation of the plane to the shader (via `Material.SetFloat` or `Material.SetVector`) and evaluate if the world positions of the hair vertices are in the correct or in the wrong side of the plane.